# The SelectCommand property has not been initialized before calling 'Fill' problem

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

The SelectCommand property has not been initialized before calling 'Fill' problem:

```
Private Sub DeleteButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DeleteButton.Click
    Dim tables As DataTableCollection
    Dim source1 As New BindingSource
    Dim row As New Integer
    Try
        ds = New DataSet
        tables = (ds.Tables)
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter
        da.Fill(ds, "Booking")
        Dim cmdstr As String = "delete * from [Booking] where ID = " & DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value.ToString()
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(cmdstr, objCon)
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        objCon.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        objCon.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't use `SelectCommand` for a non-query.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
da.SelectCommand = cmd
```

With

```
da.DeleteCommand = cmd
```

Answer (score 0):

Reguarding the `Dim` statements at the beginning of your code; you never use tables, source1 or row in your code so, there is no point in declaring them.

On to the `Try` You assign a `New DataSet` to ds. This is empty so assigned the Tables collection to tables makes no sense. This will be empty also.

Next you create a `New DataAdapter`. A new DataAdapter has no select command so it will be unable to `.Fill` anything.

Then you assign a Delete command to the SelectCommand property of a DataAdapter. This makes no sense.

Finally you execute you command. This should work if wasn't for the other code.

Keep you Database objects local so you can control their closing and disposing. `Using...End Using` takes care of this for you. The Using also acts as a Dim statement so it also declares you variables. You can include more than one variable with a single Using by separating them by a comma.

I guessed at the datatype of you ID field. Check your database.

```
Private Sub DeleteButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DeleteButton.Click
    Try
        Using cn As New OleDbConnection("Your connection string"),
                cmd As New OleDbCommand("delete * from [Booking] where ID = @ID", cn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value
            cn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```